# How can I resolve a IP address?

Tags: c++-cli

Using C++/CLI, I would like to resolve a host IP from the URL.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have the .NET framework available to you (you lucky thing), why not use:

```
IPHostEntry^ hostInfo = Dns::GetHostByName("www.blah.com");
```

This is in the `System::Net` namespace.